# How do I find an element that does not have an id, name, class, attribute, etc.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find (probably using jquery) an element that is empty/naked/etc. For example I want to find all the span elements that do not have an id, name, class, or any other attribute whatsoever.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <span> found </span>

    <span id="foo"> not found </span>

    <span name="foo"> not found </span>

    <span class="foo"> not found </span>

    <span style="width:foo"> not found </span>

    <span> found </span>

    <span foo="bar"> not found </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is incomplete without an exact piece of HTML that you want to find a particular element in.  There is no generic answer to this question - any answer has to be taylored to a specific target in a specific piece of HTML.  Your example so far is not complete HTML (no closing tags) so I assume it's just a demo, not the actual HTML you want to find something in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @adeneo for the information, `this.attributes` always returns a value. As such, I'll clean up the answer.

How to select elements that are "naked" (that do not have any attributes) using jQuery:

```
$('span').filter(function(){
    return (this.attributes.length === 0);
}).text();
```

The `.text()` method is just a placeholder, anything can be applied at that point.

[What the hell, here's a simple jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq9hL/)

Comment: It should be `span` insted of `.span`

Comment: this.attributes always returns something

Comment: @adeneo - yup, i edited my answer because i realized it may or may not do it. told ya i was winging it! haha

Comment: @jfriend00 - you don't seem to understand the nature of the question, it is a generic question about possibility. i apologize, but i cannot help with that.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The question is poorly written, and this doesn't seem to have any real world application, at least it's not a way I would use to find elements, but it does answer the question "how to find elements with no attributes" ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The reason I need this is because I am working on an html builder using contenteditable. Chrome tends to put <span> tags around random items which introduces problems, so I want to clean them up before saving the html to the database.

Answer (score 4):

Look for an empty `attributes` list:

```
var spans = $('span').filter(
  function() {
    return (this.attributes.length == 0);
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/JjAia/

Answer (score 2):

If an element doesn't have any identifying class, id, name or attribute, then the only way to find it is by its location in the hierarchy and its position in that hierarchy and, in some cases, by the attributes that it does NOT have or perhaps by the content that it has.

There is no generic answer to this question as it really depends upon your exact circumstances  and exact HTML so folks can only help you more specifically ONLY if you provide the exact HTML and tell us which element you're looking for in that HTML.

Comment: I added another span tag to my example to emphasize that you can't rely on position to find the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("span")
for(var v=0;v<elements.length;v++){
    if(elements[v].attributes.length==0){
    //your element without any attribute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through the elements and find the elements with `attributes.length == 0` http://jsfiddle.net/HjBGP/

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    if(els[i].attributes.length == 0) {
       console.log(els[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```